# Keyframes animation when changed back to display none

Tags: javascript, css

So I have a div with an animation using some keyframes. I use javascript to change the default `display: none` to `display:inline` when I click on something.

Now when I change it from `display: none` to `display:inline`, it does the animation but when I click again to hide it it doesn't. Is there any way to make the keyframe animation play when both shown and hidden? I hope it's clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: A jsfiddle would help.

Comment: display:block is not good enought ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery,

```
$(document).ready({
   $("a").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("div").toggle("slow"); // change to display: block
   });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HXj7p/)

Comment: Yeah that could work, any way to make it keep its width and only its height changing?